# deploying angular 2 app on Apache server

Tags: javascript, php, angular

I am very new to Angular 2 and just created my very first demo angular application.

to allow it to be accessible  from anywhere i want to deploy it on server.

as per instruction i have created build as well ( dist ) using

> ng build --prod

I already have shared server for my php project with Apache install on it.

So i tried to upload there. After deployment when i tries to access that url my app gets break and console showing this errors:

```
GET http://www.example.com/styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css net::ERR_ABORTED
www.example.com/:13 GET http://www.example.com/inline.7c167ae93970955c5261.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
www.example.com/:13 GET http://www.example.com/polyfills.5c847b24df1f0cb11561.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
www.example.com/:13 GET http://www.example.com/main.dbcfef8941682469b50c.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
www.example.com/:13 GET http://www.example.com/vendor.c769f33e138d82fd4650.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
www.example.com/:13 GET http://www.example.com/main.dbcfef8941682469b50c.bundle.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Is it not possible to to deploy angular and php on same server.

if yes the guidelines are highly helpfull.
thank you

Comment: in your index.html , you need to set the ``<base href>``

Comment: Did you copied the contents of the **dist** folder to the webserver?

Comment: add base tag like :
`<base href="./">`

Comment: Show you apache vhost or config

Answer (score 1):

Are you serving your demo from the root of example.com, or from some subdirectory like example.com/mydemo/? If from a subdirectory, do something like this:

ng build --prod --base-href /mydemo/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a .htaccess file (in the same directory where the index.html resides) with the following contents.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

This piece of code makes use of the mod_rewrite module from Apache, so make sure you have this enabled

Comment: You *ALSO* need to enable ` AllowOverride All` for the corresponding `<Directory> in the Apache .conf file